# Assetic doesn't generate all assets

Tags: symfony, assetic

I just ran into an issue. I pulled by newest code in production and I tried to dump all the assets however I noticed that everytime I run

```
php bin/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

I get only 5 js assets generated vs in development it is about 100 al together with css. I tried running cache clear as well and it didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your configuration, but most of the time, in `prod` environment, your assets are combined altogether and minified for faster loading.

Check your `{% javascripts %}` and `{% stylesheets %}` filters first, and more specifically the `output="xxx"` part. There are good chances this file contains your whole bulk of assets.